# How can I break one circuit when another one's current draw is high?

Tags: power, relay

A layperson here.   I own a small RV park, as well has a nice large Motor Home.  Most of my guests have the same set up in their Motor Homes as I do.  The Microwave and the Hot Water Heater are on a switch that allows you to have only one on at a time.

Very problematic in that you have to keep remembering to switch back to the Hot Water Heater every time you microwave a cup of water. This has been the same setup on my last 3 Motor Homes. Plus you NEVER have the clock set on your Microwave.

I installed a bathroom fan timer with a relay, to I can quickly twist the timer and be confident that the Hot Water Heater will go back on a short time after I use the Microwave. Can anyone help me (an electronically minded layperson), with a circuit that would let the Microwave draw enough current for the clock, but as soon has you hit the Start button and it drew say over 100 watts, the Hot Water Heater circuit would temporarily cut out. I hope this explanation made sense.

Also note that RV water heater are not like home heaters, in that they have a small element that draws about 700 watts. Maybe someone even knows of something on the market that can be used or modified?

=============================================

OK, I am sorry for not getting back and thanking you for your help.  My Father died days after I posted this and I am just now getting back to this project.

I had told my dad what I had posted here, and he ask that it I made one for my Motor Home, that I make one for his too. His has been sold, but I still want mine to work this way.

I had decided a few days ago to just get this done.

I took the below schematic to a local (local for where I was traveling,) Old TV repair guy, along with some notes I took at radio shack.  My intent was to asked the repair guy if the parts I was going to buy would work for the above diagram.  I just didn't want anything to be way off.

He said that the Bridge Rectifier would not pass through the AC current, therefor the Microwave would not work. So the circuit would not work?

So I back here to ask the experts about that.

I think you understand what I am looking for,,, When the Microwave goes from the small low watt internal light draw, to the vastly different full power cooking draw, I want a relay to open, breaking the circuit to the Hot Water Heater, so that the amp draw cant be the combination of the two.  I am OK with the relay I just don't know about sensing the draw.

Comment: Big question, is the heater 12V? Is the Microwave 12V? Or are either of the two on a 120v AC connection/transformer? And watts the wattage on the microwave?

Comment: Your old tv repair guy didn't understand my circuit. The diode bridge and resistor/3V relay would "drop" about 4.5V across it and would certainly pass current. If the microwave was rated to run at 120Vac then it would receive (after the bridge) about 115.5Vac which I'm presuming would be enough to power the microwave. Don't forget though, If the microwave is 700W, the current draw would be about 6A so the resistor would need to be rated at 18W and the bridge able to supply 6A. Sorry to hear about the old man dude.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it a try Monday, and report back here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would consider: -

[image]

In series with the microwave is a bridge rectifier capable of taking the microwave load current and AC voltage. On the DC side of the bridge is a power resistor in parallel with a low voltage relay such as 5V rating (or maybe even lower if you can get one). The power resistor is chosen so that when the microwave takes full load current, there is sufficient voltage across the relay coil so that it activates and turns the heater off.

When the microwave is done cooking, the voltage across the relay drops sufficiently and the relay drops-out and power is restored to the water heater. Here's a 3V relay made by Panasonic. It's got NO and NC contacts rated at 8A up to 250Vac. The order code (209-5597 ids for Farnell a UK electrical supplier so it's probably irrelevant in other parts of the world): -

[image]

The relay coil is 90 ohms and activates on (say) 2A taken by the microwave, the resistor and 90 ohm coil have to "drop" (say) 3V. This means coil and resistor together form a 1.5 ohm value. Clearly, as the relay is 90 ohms you can use a 1.5 ohm resistor. The thing to watch on this circuit is the microwave current. If it is (say) 2A max, then the resistor will dissipate about 6W and this is a little on the high side. Any more than 2A and I think I'd recommend a different technique using an opto-isolater built where the relay coil is shown. This could then activate a normal AC relay via fairly standard techniques.

Please let us know what the microwave current is when heating food and what is when just powering its clock - this is important to know for this design to work.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have re-edited my post with more information.

Comment: Ok, I am back on this project.  I have bought a couple Bridge Rectifiers, and they do not pass current to the Microwave ?   I thought maybe it was an electronics issue but tried a blow dryer and battery charger,,, The BridgeRectifier does not seem to be conductive across the AC poles?  What am I missing.  Thanks

Comment: Without the relay and appropriate shunt resistor connected, there will be no current flow thru the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase what you are saying, it seems the microwave will be connected all the time and the only question is whether the water heater will be switched off or not.  This then comes down to sensing current going to the microwave and turning off the water heater power when the microwave current goes above some limit.

You want the switch not to trip from the clock in the microwave or when the door is opened and the light goes on, just when the microwave is actually heating something.  Fortunately, the ratio of the heating current to the light current should be large, so this should not be a problem.

For sensing the current, I'd use a *current transformer* in the hot lead to the microwave.  A little electronic circuit can detect the output above some set level and energize a relay when the current is sensed to be high.  That means the unergerized state of the relay allows the water heater to draw current, with the energized state turning it off.  This is on the theory that the microwave will be on a small fraction of the overall time, so the normal quiescient state doesn't draw any power.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have re-edited my post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09VDKSYV4) (current sensing relay) with a relay. when it senses microwave oven current, use another relay to shut off power to the water heater. When microwave is done, relay will switch back and give water heater power again.